# Monitoring Tomcat in a Java program using JMXProxyServlet

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy, jmx

I'm trying to monitor Tomcat in Java program but I don't how I should pass the username and password to `JMXProxyServlet`. Does any one have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to use a Java program to monitor Tomcat, or are you using something else? I ask because you mention both Java and `JMXProxyServlet`. If you have a persistent Java program running to monitor, you might just want to make a persistent JMX connection to Tomcat and use that instead of making lots of requests to the `JMXProxyServlet`.

Comment: I want to monitor Tomcat using JMXProxy servlet periodically and to automate the procedure I want to use Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your monitoring software will be written in Java. You can configure your manager webapp to use HTTP BASIC authentication and a MemoryRealmDatabase (which is how it's set up by default). Then,

- Enable a user in `tomcat-users.xml` with the `manager-jmx` role.
- Verify that HTTP BASIC authentication is working using a regular web browser.
- Set an 'Authorization' HTTP header along with your HTTP request to `JMXProxyServlet`. The value of that header should be `base64(username + ":" + password)`.

Various HTTP helper libraries (like [Apache httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)) have specialized methods to help you do this, or you can use `HttpURLConnection` directly.